# Retrive row by row data from recordset in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

One of my pl/sql package. I need to print a specific field from a recordset.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE logDetailsPack AS
   TYPE MSG_TXT IS RECORD(LOC_MSG XX_FS_MOB_LOG.MESSAGE_TEXT%TYPE);
   TYPE MSG_TAB IS TABLE OF MSG_TXT;
   C_MSG MSG_TAB;
   PROCEDURE getLog;
END logDetailsPack;
```

and my package body is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY logDetailsPack AS
  PROCEDURE getLog IS
  CURSOR C1 IS SELECT MESSAGE_TEXT FROM XX_FS_MOB_LOG;
  BEGIN
    OPEN C1;
    FETCH C1 BULK COLLECT INTO C_MSG; 
    FOR COUNTER IN 1..500 LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('Message : '|| C_MSG.LOC_MSG(COUNTER));
    END LOOP;
  END getLog;
END  logDetailsPack;
```

Here `C_MSG` is the name of my record set and `LOC_MSG` is the field in the record set. How can I loop through this and print `LOC_MSG`

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

1. There is really no need to use a record ADT. You have only one item, you could
   declare the `msg_tab` type as follows:

   ```
   type msg_tab is table of xx_fs_mob_log.message_text%type;
   ```
2. There is also no need to use a cursor in this particular situation.

Having said that, your package might look like this:

```
create or replace package logdetailspack as
  type msg_tab is table of xx_fs_mob_log.message_text%type;
  c_msg msg_tab;
  procedure getlog;
end logdetailspack;

create or replace package body logdetailspack as
   procedure getlog is
   begin
     select message_text 
       bulk collect into c_msg
       from xx_fs_mob_log;
     for counter c_msg.first..c_msg.last
     loop
       dbms_output.put_line('message : '|| c_msg(counter));
     end loop;
   exception
     when no_data_found
     then dbms_output('Select returns no rows') 
   end getlog;
 end  logdetailspack;
```